# CSS/JS optimizer for Java/Spring/Thymeleaf application?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

In a Java/Spring/Themeleaf application, how can CSS/JS optimization be enabled in code only, without adding another component outside the platform (e.g. Apache)?

I'm talking about optimizations like this:

- https://github.com/JonathanWalsh/Granule

which is in Java but has its own syntax and not integrated with Spring MVC or Thymeleaf, besides being last updated seven years ago,

and this:

- https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-prioritize-critical-css
- https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-css-combine
- https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-js-combine
- https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/filter-js-minify

which looks great but runs on Apache. I understand I could stick an Apache server between our CDN Reverse Proxy and App Servers, but that's a whole new level of complexity and right now I'm looking for a developer-oriented solution that can be managed as part of the application code within Java / Spring / Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/wro4j/wro4j it has both compile and runtime options to combine and minify JS and CSS resources.

It has also has option for [wro4spring-thymeleaf-dialect](https://github.com/sevensource/wro4spring-thymeleaf-dialect) which is not maintained anymore.